Is there a way to delay a screenshot using Greenshot?
I need to do a few clicks before in order to get what I want to screen capture.
Is there a way to delay a screenshot using Greenshot?

What about using other software to capture the screen (or area of screen)?

@RomeoNinov not necessary, Greenshot natively supports this.

Yes, Greenshot natively supports this.
By default there is a 100ms delay, but you can change this in the settings.
In addition, if the print screen key is normally captured, you can just perform the action, then press it and even if the screen changes afterwards, Greenshot will create an entire screenshot first, shows you that screenshot, and lets you draw on it what you want to capture of it.
But if you really want to change the delay, open the settings, tab screenshot, then the last setting in the top frame. Hard to miss really.

Use the built-in Windows snipping/screenshot tool instead of Greenshot. The built in tool freezes the screen at the moment you use it so you can bring up menus via right click or other actions and they won't simply vanish. I use it regularly for documentation.
Perform the clicks you need then press the hotkey combination of Win+Shift+S. This behaviour was also added to the PrintScreen key in later editions of Windows 10.
This will "freeze" the screen and then bring up a bar at the top of the screen where you can use a rectangle to select a specific area, a lasso tool, a windows select tool, or a full screen capture.
Once you have selected the area or screen or windows to capture you will get a notification which you can click to open the Snip & Sketch tool and from there either copy the screenshot to the clipboard or save it to a file.

Screenshot uses the exact same principle. You press prt-scrn and it makes a capture of that moment, even if the screen changes afterwards.
